# How to troubleshoot C# IIS-hosted WCF NET TCP service timeout issues

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, network-programming

I have inherited a C# web service hosted by IIS on Windows Server 2019 that is having a problem that I'm struggling to track down.

The WCF service listens on port 82 for http connections, and on port 8002 for net tcp connections;  the IIS config for the site has it's Bindings set to `http:*:82:,net.tcp:8002:*`

However, when the service has been running for a few hours it stops responding on the net tcp port (8002) - other apps that attempt to connect to it end up timing out:

`System.TimeoutException: The open operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. ---> System.TimeoutException: The socket transfer timed out after 00:01:00. You have exceeded the timeout set on your binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`

Yet connections to the http port (82) still work as expected, so the service is still running.

Recycling the appropriate app pool causes the net tcp connections to start working properly again, which suggests to me that it might be some sort of resource leak, but I can see nothing obvious in the code, and it doesn't appear to be a lack of memory.

I'm at a loss as to how to troubleshoot this further - any suggestions?

Comment: Never use port numbers under 1000 they are reserved for standard protocols and are often blocked by virus checkers.  Sop change the port number form 82 to a different number.  To debug issue from cmd.exe use >Netstat -a (run on both client and server) which will give the status of the connections for each port.  The Server must be listening on the port.  The connection from client to server also must be fully closed for a new connection to be made from same client IP.  Usually cases like this are due to old connection never closing.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing You might get some initial ideas from tracing, but hang dump analysis or a profiler might be quicker (but skills required).

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, the problem may be that the number of connected clients exceeds the maximum capacity of the server-side, and the server can't handle it. If the client-side waits for a timeout, the TimeoutException will appear.

You can view the maximum number of connections for the service through the following code:

```
        NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
        Console.WriteLine(binding.MaxConnections);
```

This is a reference link for maxconnections:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.maxconnections?view=netframework-4.8

There is servicethrottling property in WCF service, which specifies the restriction mechanism of windows communication foundation (WCF) service.
You can prevent excessive consumption of resources by setting serviceThrottling in the service.

The following configuration example specifies that the service limits the maximum concurrent calls to 2, and the maximum number of concurrent instances to 10.

[image]

In order to prevent excessive consumption of resources, the channel needs to be closed after each call by the client-side.

```
       ServiceReference1.Service1Client service1Client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        service1Client.GetData(0);
        service1Client.Close();
```

For more information about serviceThrottling, please refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/servicethrottling